# Python + pyQT - send parameters to the connected Signal function

Tags: python, function, parameters, combobox, pyqt

This example works: (Here my function has no input parameters)

```
    QtCore.QObject.connect(ComboJobType1_1, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("currentIndexChanged(QString)")) ,self.InputChanged())
```

But, It is necessary for me to send a parameter so I try this: (After updating my function to expect one parameter):

QtCore.QObject.connect(ComboJobType1_1, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("currentIndexChanged(QString)")) ,self.InputChanged("ComboJobType1_1"))

Please note that the first example is working, the only problem (I guess) is sending a parameter to my function (I must know the name of the comboBox when I'm in the function).

Please advice...
Thank you!
Wish you a great day,
Dolphin

Comment: After searching some similar questions, I tried the following:

QtCore.QObject.connect(ComboJobType1_1, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("currentIndexChanged(QString)")) ,lambda objName = "ComboJobType1_1": self.InputChanged(objName))

My function , for this try is:
 def InputChanged(self,objName):
        print objName 

And what I see in the print results is the selected value in my ComboBox and not the string I sent to my function...

Please advice...... Thank you

Answer (score 3):

ref https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/04/25/passing-extra-arguments-to-pyqt-slot

```
    button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.on_button(1))
    button2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.on_button(2))

def on_button(self, n):
    print('Button {0} clicked'.format(n))
```

worked for me, tht gives it a simple lambda (turn it to funciton ref instead of execute ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the emitting object ("from_object") and the slot handler ("self.my_handler"):

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(from_object, QtCore.SIGNAL("nameOfSignal(QString)"), self.my_handler)
```

Comment: Good morning, I managed to make it worked.
Thanks anyway.
I tried again the example with the lamda and now it's ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can import partial function to pass arguments to slot function.

```
from functools import partial

QtCore.QObject.connect(ComboJobType1_1, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("currentIndexChanged(QString)")) ,partial(self.InputChanged, "ComboJobType1_1"))
```