# How to pass a string from a widget that closes when clicked using PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, user-interface, pyqt5, widget

I made a widget that prompts the user to browse and select a filepath.  I would like to copy this filepath string such that I can keep the string once the first widget is closed. In this way, I can pass this string to other widgets that I have not yet coded.

The code snippet below will successfully prompt the user and will show the correct filepath via gui. But, the `print` statement outputs `None` instead of the filepath string. The `print` statement refers to the line `print("\n .. FPATH:\n{}\n".format(file_selection_widget.fpath))`. **My question is: why is this happening?** I tried changing `self.close()` from the inner scope to `file_selection_widget.close()` in the outer scope (in `__main__`), but this causes the user prompt to fail; I'm not sure what else could be wrong here.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets #, QtGui, QtCore

class FileSelectionWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    """
    This class allows the user to select the input
    data file to be read via gui.
    """

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self._fpath = None
        super().__init__(parent)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click here and select the data file you want to read")
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)

    @property
    def fpath(self):
        return self._fpath

    def on_clicked(self):
        self.prompt_input_file()
        self.prompt_verification()

    def prompt_input_file(self):
        fpath, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            None, 'Select input file', '/home', '',
            options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        self._fpath = fpath
        self.close()

    def prompt_verification(self):
        alert = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        alert.setText('The input filepath you selected is: \n{}'.format(self.fpath)) # shows correct filepath
        alert.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ## initialize application
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    ## select path of input data file
    file_selection_widget = FileSelectionWidget()
    file_selection_widget.show()

    print("\n .. FPATH:\n{}\n".format(file_selection_widget.fpath)) ## shows incorrect filepath

    ## ... back end loads data file and processes data
    ## ... more gui

    ## exit application
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets #, QtGui, QtCore

class FileSelectionWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    """
    This class allows the user to select the input
    data file to be read via gui.
    """

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self._fpath = None
        super().__init__(parent)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click here and select the data file you want to read")
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)

    @property
    def fpath(self):
        return self._fpath

    def on_clicked(self):
        self.prompt_input_file()
        self.prompt_verification()

    def prompt_input_file(self):
        fpath, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            None, 'Select input file', '/home', '',
            options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        self._fpath = fpath
        print("Your Selected Path :\n{}\n".format(file_selection_widget.fpath)) ## shows incorrect filepath
        self.close()
        

    def prompt_verification(self):
        alert = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        alert.setText('The input filepath you selected is: \n{}'.format(self.fpath)) # shows correct filepath
        alert.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    file_selection_widget = FileSelectionWidget()
    file_selection_widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I understand that putting the `print` statement in the application loop before running `self.close()` will work. Thank you for showing an example of this. But, my question is about how to *pass* this string to the outer scope (where it can be printed) or to another widget. Otherwise, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784084/how-to-pass-arguments-to-functions-by-the-click-of-button-in-pyqt/38777350#38777350) will also print.